# Binding data to recycleview, with more items data on a viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

[image: My expect]

As you saw picture above, i want to binding data same design and data like the picture.
I used recycle view to do that. I tried to use girdlayoutmanager to separate row 1 to 2 columns, but i cant not.
Then i custom a layout like row 1, but with each data in list it will generate a viewholder.

Can anyone suggest me some solutions for this problem. Thank so much!

Comment: You should be able to do this with getItemViewType(). You will need create two different view holder classes. You can see how to do it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/5124783

Answer (score 0):

When you bind data into Adapter that time given list in that `onBindViewHolder()` method call get value from the list then make if condition and hide view according to the value like below example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user=mUserLsit.get(position);
    if(user.getData()==Data1){
        holder.mTvPwd.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }
}
```

then when you need that view that time visiable the view.

Comment: So how you solve to bind Data1, Data2, Data 3 to one viewholder?

Comment: make pojo class for all data then after on bind get the pojo data and check data value and bind data into view according view.